# After applying for loop in robot framework , Error came as follows- Keyword name cannot be empty

Tags: python, appium, robotframework

I am applying for loops in robot framework in which i created a list of two methods. So what this loop it will traverse through the methods and run the method one by one.But after running the code it throws the error -Keyword name cannot be empty.

PF the Code.

```
Multiple_Users_Signin
  @{ITEMS}  Create List    Ellie_Profile  Leo_Profile
  :FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    @{ITEMS}
  \    Log    ${ELEMENT}
  \    ${ELEMENT}
```

Multiple_Users_Sign in is the keyword i had defined for the for loop method that i am using in other robot script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be a bit more explicit than that - you have to use `Run Keyword` if you want to pass a string that the framework should resolve to a keyword:

```
Multiple_Users_Signin
  @{ITEMS}  Create List    Ellie_Profile  Leo_Profile
  :FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    @{ITEMS}
  \    Log    ${ELEMENT}
  \    Run Keyword    ${ELEMENT}
```

Answer (score 5):

In your code , inside loop,in last line , RF will treat **${ELEMENT}** as an argument, and **RF** is looking for a **KW** to which this arguments belongs.

Since you have not provided any **KW** , it returned correct error.

```
Multiple_Users_Signin
  @{ITEMS}  Create List    Ellie_Profile  Leo_Profile
  :FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    @{ITEMS}
  \    Log    ${ELEMENT}
  \    ${ELEMENT}
```

**modified code**

```
Multiple_Users_Signin
      @{ITEMS}  Create List    Ellie_Profile  Leo_Profile
      :FOR    ${ELEMENT}    IN    @{ITEMS}
      \    Log    ${ELEMENT}
      #\    ${ELEMENT}
```

Comment: Depending on the version of RF you're using, the for loop syntax may need to change.

Comment: If the last line is removed, the OP's intent won't happen - to execute a keyword with that name.

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the last line it should work. Problem is that you miss the keyword name.